# Tomato Disease treatment

Tags: tomatoes, diseases

[image]My Tomato leaves are getting Yellow. I assume it some sort of disease. Until now I just tried to spray garlic on them, but it does not help. How can I treat it?

Comment: Hmm, looks as if its on its last legs - pity the picture doesn't show what its growing in. It looks as if its run out of root room (maybe in a pot?) or has been exposed to cold temperatures, or is an old plant. More info please?

Comment: While the leaves look nitrogen deficient on the first view, this may only be a symptom. I'll have to ask some questions:

- How much water does the tomato get usually (many people give too much)?
- What type of substrate is the plant growing in?
- what about direct sunlight? (in which country are you living?)
- please post a photo of the whole plant

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be a nitrogen or magnesium deficiency but without more information or pictures it is very difficult to say.